# Alternate way to use DuplicateOutput() of IDXGIOutput1 in C# for UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, screen-capture, sharpdx

Is there any way to use the [DuplicateOutput()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh404600) method of IDXGIOutput1 interface to get desktop duplication currently it is available in C++, I want to use it in C#. The DuplicateOutput() is only available for desktop I want it to implement in UWP, so please specify any alternate way for this.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a [windows runtime component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh441569.aspx) and write your own DuplicateOutput method by some [supported win32 APIs in UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-and-com-for-uwp-apps). Then, you could add reference to this component in C# UWP project.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing a general UWP app, then, this API is not available in UWP. You could check the [Win32 and COM APIs for UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-and-com-for-uwp-apps) for more details.

If you're not going to publish your app to windows store,that is, you might want to side-load your app. Then, you could choose the [Brokered Windows Runtime Components for a side-loaded Windows Store app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps). If you use the brokered windows runtime components, you would be able to use this API.